# Hibernate/JPA: Join on columns of different types

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot (3.2.3 vers) application I have the following two JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_1")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Table1 {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Table1ID id;

    @Column(name = "tt_xx")
    private String xx;

    @Column(name = "tt_yy")
    private String yy;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ts_id", referencedColumnName = "tt_id")
    private List<Table2> t2List;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class Table1ID {

        @Convert(converter = PaddingConverter.class)
        @Column(name = "tt_id")
        private String ttID;

    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_2")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Table2 {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Table2ID id;

    @Column(name = "ts_xx")
    private String xx;

    @Column(name = "ts_yy")
    private String yy;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class Table2ID {

        @Column(name = "ts_id")
        private String tsID;

        @Column(name = "ts_key")
        private String tsKey;

    }
}
```

So, in my DB I have two tables: *table_1*, *table_2*:

- table_1: has as primary key the column *tt_id* which is of type DECIMAL(8) on the database.
- table_2: has as primary key the columns *ts_id* (VARCHAR(8)) and ts_key.

As you could see in the entities, and for reasons of business logic, I applied a converter to tt_id of table_1 so that in the application we have a value of the type '00012345' for db values 12345.
In table_2 however this is already so since the value on the db precisely is already a string including the leading zeros.

The problem is that the OneToMany relationship I am mapping seems not to be working. It seems that Hibernate does not apply the converter.
I also tried defining a relation like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "tt_id", value = "CAST(ts_id AS DECIMAL)")
private List<Table2> t2List;
```

but I get the error "Values involves formula".

Hibernate vers: 6.4.1 Final

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly hinders you to change the data type of the columns (or in worst case add another column with a fitting datatype)? Also I wonder if putting the left-padding of your ids into application logic rather than into your database could be the better option.

Comment: I can't change the database definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be saying that have a difference in the type/format of a key in one table and a foreign key in another table that refers to it, because of business logic.

Keys in a database should be opaque - i.e. not affected by business logic.

My recommendation is to make the keys something opaque and auto-populating, preferably an int with an auto increment, and make sure that the the key and foreign key match exactly in type and value.

You can still keep the "business" data in other columns if you need it, just keep it out of the primary keys.

This is for two reasons:

1. This is "how it's supposed to work" - the join will be more efficient without any sort of conversion, and hibernate will "just work"
2. Simplicity - there will be less to go wrong, less to maintain, and you can spend your time writing business logic instead of fooling around with trying to make the tools do things that they weren't designed for.

Comment: I agree with you, but it doesn't solve my current problem :)

Comment: Yes, I see that after I answered, you added a comment stating that you can't alter the existing tables. The only other idea that I have is, if you are working with a database that supports updatable views, like MySQL, you might be able to create views that combine the pieces of the compound keys into simple keys, and make them all of the same type. Then you might be able to use the views with Hibernate instead of using the tables directly.